# Is it possible to use chaplin with meteor?

Tags: backbone.js, meteor

is it possible to use [chaplin](https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin) with meteor?

Any idea, advice, pointers or guidance is very welcome.

Comment: I haven't tried Meteor, but I would give [Brunch with Chaplin|https://github.com/paulmillr/brunch-with-chaplin] a look. Brunch has similar features of Meteor, except Brunch doesn't have the easy DB interaction.

Comment: @CamelBlues, Brunch and Meteor are very different. Brunch is javascript scaffolding, and build tool. And Meteor is client-to-server end-to-end framework, with its own APIs for DB, comm etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with Chaplin. But after having a look at its home page and 5 min intro reading. I understood that it is only client side, and its well-defined application architecture for backbone. so yes you can use that with Meteor, like backbone can be used with Meteor. (Have a look at Meteor packages, http://docs.meteor.com/#meteorlist backbone is already supported).

There will be few things, which may conflict with meteor features. i.e. Backbone support REST remote sync with server, and meteor provide their own collection management with server sync, but you can use either of it based on your requirement. so In short, yes it should be possible to use chaplin with meteor.

Comment: I tried to integrate Chaplin's AMD build with Meteor using RequireJS, so I provide [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) with such [config](https://gist.github.com/2935219), since Chaplin has dependencies on jQuery, underscore and Backbone. It works but not optimal, 'coz Meteor loads Backbone via [http://localhost:3000/packages/backbone/backbone.js?21733827a5501133619b8ac4533201267d1afa3f] but RequireJS loads Backbone via [http://localhost:3000/packages/backbone/backbone.js].  
My problem now become what's the best practice to get RequireJS loads the js files in Meteor's way.